# UEFI Install - mmc0 unknown controller version (3) Error

Tags: system-installation, usb, uefi

Installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 via USB Drive
PC = ZOTAC ZBOX Magnus EN970

When booting to the USB Drive, it boots in UEFI mode (no splash screen). Selecting any of the options (Try Ubuntu, Install, or OEM Install) all result in the same error:

mmc0 unknown controller version (3)

I've searched, and it seems this is because the SD Card reader may not be supported. I can't figure out how to disable it in the UEFI installer though.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

So far, I've ensured the ZBOX Bios have been updated. I've tried multiple programs to create the bootable USB drive. I've also tried forcing it to boot in legacy mode, instead of UEFI to no avail.

Comment: Check for AHCI/RAID settings and if the latter change it to the former. The problem is not that though, you're being misled by a "normal" (can be ignored) error message (it should boot the live session even if the internal storage isn't detected or with no storage at all). The problem is it never boots graphically due to the high-end Nvidia graphics included for which the additional `nomodeset` boot parameter is required until the Nvidia proprietary drivers are installed.

Comment: Storage options are set to AHCI. How do you pass the nomideset parameter without the graphical interface? Could you point me to the right resource? I’m new to Linux for the most part, and just haven’t had any success thus far trying to use that parameter.

Comment: At the first menu select "try Ubuntu", press "e" to edit and add `nomodeset` after `quiet splash`.

Comment: Thanks! Using 'nomodeset', and booting into safemode allowed me to install the OS, purge the nVidia drivers, then reinstall them. All is working now. Thank you for the help.