# Live USB doesnt boot up! (Error installing Ubuntu on Lenovo Thinkpad E580)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lenovo, thinkpad

Im new in this forum! i just bought a Thinkpad E580 windows on it and im trying to install Linux(Ubuntu) alongside windows 10.
I have installed Ubuntu earlier on other laptops!
Here i get an Error after loading the Ubuntu logo:

mmc0 unknown controller version (3). you may experience problems

Thats it and then its just this terminal like black screen where i can type in commands.
I searched on the Forums : people were saying putting nomodeset in the boot parameters. i tried that aswell and it didnt work.(im not sure if i did it wrong but read several forums how to do it)
Note: i have tried the LTS version and the latest version same problem.

Edit: there is another error: "(initramfs) unable to find a live medium containing a live file system"

please help me !
Best Regards
Amin

Comment: Perhaps this is might help:  [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999544/uefi-install-mmc0-unknown-controller-version-3-error)   Specifically, the "nomodeset" might get you further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried "nomodeset" and it didnt work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE for SOLUTION : 
I managed to fix both Problems
 - found out that mmc0 is the sd card reader which isnt getting recognized or something of a kind, so i entered BIOS Setup and turned off the sd card reader, the error disappeared.
- for the second error at the end, found out that i should use a 2.0 Usb Port to boot up from, which i plugged a 3.0 Usb drive in but it didnt work, so i tried using a 2.0 Usb drive in the 2.0 Usb Port, That worked fine. It was the USB PORT and VERSION

Installed Ubuntu and everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Is the machine boot in the Grub menu? When the Ubuntu logo is shown, did you try to press enter to access some parameters? We choose the E585 model and must tweak the bootline to do a fresh install in the Grub menu. The tweak can be made in Win Ten also (Ubiquity).

Expert mode in the Ubuntu Logo or pressing e in the Grub menu in Try or Install Ubuntu.

You must add a space at the end of the linux line and type *iommu=soft*

*nomodeset* doesn't work here. There are several *ivrs* arguments that work, but not after Kernel 4.19.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

The GRUB is loaded and i press on the "try ubuntu.." and the ubuntu logo shows i press enter and parameters show which i listed above. I was about to try your solution but managed to fix the peoblem i will post as answer

Comment: click e in the Grub menu